# i am having so many logs with the tag IMGMapper. Idont know how to solve or disable this log showing in my android studio for Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, samsung-mobile

E/IMGMapper(21086): set:488 set: Unset optional value from type SMPTE2086
E/IMGMapper(21086): set:488 set: Unset optional value from type CTA861_3
E/IMGMapper(21086): set:488 set: Unset optional value from type SMPTE2086
E/IMGMapper(21086): set:488 set: Unset optional value from type CTA861_3
E/IMGMapper(21086): set:488 set: Unset optional value from type SMPTE2086

**i have been using Samsung mobile for debug my Flutter app in Android studio, but I dont know to disable this log... Help it solve**

Comment: Has anyone figured out what this error actually *IS*, and how to get rid of it?  I don't want to *fold* it so it doesn't appear in the log, I want to *FIX THE PROBLEM* so it doesn't appear in the log in the first place.  What's causing this problem?  Does anyone know?

Comment: I think its because of the new developer tools and options on android mobiles... other than that the code is working fine while debugging in other mobile phones..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fold those messages go to settings:

File > Settings > Editor > General > Console

Look for section:

Fold console lines that contain

Click the + button on right hand side of scrollable list

Add your substring of what you'd like hidden from the Console output.

[image]

Comment: Sry I have already did that , but thank you for taking time to answer my question