# Too many 'E/IMGMapper( 4104): set:488 set: Unset optional value from type' logs in the console

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, console

I'm debugging my Flutter app in a Samsung phone. How do I disable these logs in VSCode.

[i am having so many logs with the tag IMGMapper. Idont know how to solve or disable this log showing in my android studio for Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75862486/i-am-having-so-many-logs-with-the-tag-imgmapper-idont-know-how-to-solve-or-disa)

This question has already been asked but problem still exists. It talks about log folding in Android studio, how do I fold these console logs in VS code.

Answer (score 0):

You should check this thread: [Weird adb logs, I get a lot of these logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75277489/weird-adb-logs-i-get-a-lot-of-these-logs)

There appears to be android build source code that causes this issue. You can either fold messages in Android Studio Code:

```
Settings -> Console -> Add Message to fold
```

Or in VSCode you can use the exclamation point to hide certain messages:

```
!IMGMapper
```

Comment: I'm using VSCode, where do I put this exclamation ?

Comment: You would do this if you are running in the debug console. On the right side there will be a filter box.